# index of nth match of regular expression in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone please help me in finding the index of 5th match of the Regex (matches * not inside double quotes) in the following string?

```
ABC*DEF*PQR*"LMN*ABC"*XYZ*MNO*ABC*XYZ
```

i.e. 25 (just before MNO)

please help with the C# code to write the value 25 on the console output.

I used the Regex: `\*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The regex you are using is very inefficient and might cause issues in the long run.

Comment: I only googled the Regex, can you please suggest an efficient one?

Comment: can there be multiple double quotes like `abc"abc" nncknfjsk "sjnfsn"`?

Comment: no, double quotes are text qualifier here only.

Comment: you can check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/lF5iX0/3)**

Comment: its just a genaralized form..you can find any `*` as long as there are one pair of `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string text = "ABC*DEF*PQR*\"LMN* ABC\"*XYZ*MNO*ABC*XYZ";
string pattern = "\\*(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(matches[4].Index); // indexing from 0, so 4, not 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a regex that will solve the problem. Only limitation is if you enter more than present double quotes in the string, it will lead to *catastrophic backtracking*

```
(?:(?:(?:[^*"]*)(?:"[^"]*")*)*(\*)){5}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5iX0/2)**